# Cannot get Laptop to load grub dual boot Windows and Linux

Tags: grub

I am a little lost after installing Windows next to my Linux partition. When I start the computer, grub is loaded and I have to manually start linux by

```
set root=(x)
linux /boot/xxx root=/dev/yyy
initd /boot/zzz
boot
```

In theory, I should be able to run update-grub after startup and the entry should be added to grub right?

In practice I figure I have to mount the boot partiti and reinstall grub there, update it and potentially create a new config (Here, I do not really know what that is..)

So:

```
[17:58:52] marius :: DeepThought  ➜  ~ » sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
[17:59:27] marius :: DeepThought  ➜  ~ » sudo update-grub                   1 ↵
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.9
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.9
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

This should be it, from my understanding, but it does not work.

I can also do:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/grub/grub.cfg
```

, but it does not help.

There are the partitions:

```
[18:05:45] marius :: DeepThought  ➜  ~ » sudo blkid   
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="53FC-45F0" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a2ef2964-433c-4573-bbce-32e00984ef2a"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="DA7E06347E0609C9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e621fdb2-daf6-4403-9a41-f0a7adf0dd31"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="92eed5c7-fd3d-4fee-b132-a1130b3fdb5e" UUID_SUB="6ff00ccc-8050-4702-852f-4c2d4e27d390" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="434eb7f2-e323-45b5-869e-5617bb1a4732"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="e75df4a9-a8b2-4041-9407-60760afbf089"
```

Any help and explanation of what is going on is welcome :)

EDIT:

Got it, I have to edit my initial question.

Here is the output of fstab:

```
[19:31:19] marius :: DeepThought  ➜  ~ » cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/nvme0n1p2
UUID=92eed5c7-fd3d-4fee-b132-a1130b3fdb5e   /           btrfs       rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/    0 0

# /dev/nvme0n1p1
#UUID=53FC-45F0         /boot/efi   vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2


UUID=53FC-45F0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

I was myself surprised to find btrfs instead of ext4. Then again it worked before the Windows install as well.

Comment: if you have a separate /boot partition, it must be Linux formatted, usually ext4. But ESP must be FAT32 formatted with esp,boot flags. Do you have two NVMe drives? And ESP on each? But UEFI install must then be to --efi-directory=/boot/efi. If you have correct ESP mounted with fstab, you can just run `sudo grub-install` which uses all defaults.

Comment: I have one nvme drive, the first partition in FAT format is the ESP partition. My Linux paritition is in btrfs format, Windows in ntfs. 

The efi partition has to be FAT formatted, why do you say it has to be ext4? 

I tried the grub-install with  --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi , but it did not help.

Here ist the content of my fstab: 

`# /dev/nvme0n1p1
#UUID=53FC-45F0       /boot/efi  vfat       rw,relatime,fmask=0022,d
mask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-r
o 0 2


UUID=53FC-45F0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
`

Comment: Please do not post in comments terminal output. Difficult to read. Do you have ESP mounted twice?Or is first line with double # commented it out? You showed a entry with this: :--efi-directory=/mnt/bootf". Most that use /boot have that separte from / and often ext4, but can be any Linux format. Do not know anything about btrfs. I think most users I have seen use ext4 for smaller / and then other formats for data.

Comment: I update my initial message above. 

installing grub with the /mnt/boot does not work either..

Comment: Do not know btrfs. It has sub partitions of some sort and requires unique setting to mount & repair. And different repair tools.

Comment: Does anyone else has an idea? The problem remains..